# Cloud foundry spring boot data source pool configuration

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I am using spring boot and use postgres , rabbit mq and deploying application on CF. We figured that we need to set connection pool, we found that whatever configuration we do, on CF we can its max 4 connections, not sure from where we get that number (probably  something with buildpack or service config).

In order to resolve that I had to extend AbstractCloudConfig, and that is pain as it turns off other auto configuration so now I have to manually configure rabbit mq connection factory too:(. I have came up with below configuration, but not sure this is right way.

Spring boot version: 1.4

Please advise.

```
package com.example;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.config.java.AbstractCloudConfig;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

/**
 * If we need to modify some some custom service configuration on cloud foundry
 * e.g. setting up of connection pools. If we set normally and expose bean, it
 * will work fine on local machine. But as it will go to Cloud foundry it
 * somehow creates max 4 connections. (Not sure from where this number comes)
 * 
 * Adding this configuration meaning we no longer want to leverage auto
 * configuration. As soon as Spring boot sees this bean in cloud profile it will
 * turn of auto configuration. Expectation is application is going to take care
 * of all configuration. This normally works for most of the applications.
 * 
 * For more information read: https://github.com/dsyer/cloud-middleware-blog
 * https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/spring-service-bindings.html
 *
 * Hopefully future release of spring boot will allow us to hijack only
 * configuration that we want to do ourselves and rest will be auto
 * configuration specifically in context with CloudFoundry.
 *
 */
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class CloudServicesConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

    @Value("${vcap.services.postgres.credentials.jdbc_uri}")
    private String postgresUrl;

    @Value("${vcap.services.postgres.credentials.username}")
    private String postgresUsername;

    @Value("${vcap.services.postgres.credentials.password}")
    private String postgresPassword;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String dataSourceDriverClassName;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(dataSourceDriverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(postgresUrl);
        dataSource.setUsername(postgresUsername);
        dataSource.setPassword(postgresPassword);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(10);
        dataSource.setMaxIdle(5);
        dataSource.setMinIdle(5);
        dataSource.setMaxActive(25);
        return dataSource;
    }

    // You can add rest of services configuration below e.g. rabbit connection
    // factory, redis etc to centralize services configuration for cloud.
    // This example did not use profile but that is what you should use to
    // separate out cloud vs local configuraion to help run on local etc.

}
```

Comment: Found these: https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/221898227-Connection-pool-warning-message-maxIdle-is-larger-than-maxActive-setting-maxIdle-to-4-seen-in-PCF-deployed-Spring-app and https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-connectors/blob/master/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/service/relational/DbcpLikePooledDataSourceCreator.java

Comment: are you deploying fat jar or .war

Comment: jar as it is spring boot!

Comment: This is a very informative article about all of the ways you can configure a data source in Springboot with Cloud Foundry. https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry

Answer (score 2):

You don't need all that configuration just to customize the pool size. You should just need this code as shown in the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server):

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(5, 30, 3000);
    DataSourceConfig dbConfig = new DataSourceConfig(poolConfig, null);
    return connectionFactory().dataSource(dbConfig);
}
```